# Why can't I play android sound pitch above 1.8?

Tags: android, audio, pitch

I'm trying to write a music app capable of playing midi files in sync with user input. I've got as far as creating custom view, playing sounds, and reading MIDI data. Now I am trying to play the MIDI notes. I use

```
sounds.play(tone, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, x.x);
```

This works fine playing a 66kb sample except for higher pitches. According to the docs, pitch x.x ranges from 0.5 (half speed, octave below) to 2.0 (twice speed, octave above). However, when I try a pitch above 1.8, I get an AudioTrack error, "AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -22. I can also actually use a value lower than 0.5, contrary to the documentation.

What is stopping the use of values above 1.8?